# Install Windows certiciate inside Vagrant box via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vagrant

I want to install Windows certificate in Windows based Vagrant machine via PowerShell.

I tried to use this command

```
 vagrant.exe powershell - c "Import-Certificate -Filepath C:\vagrant\Microcosm.cer"
```

But I revived an error

```
vagrant.exe : The machine with the name '-' was not found configured for
At line:1 char:1
+ vagrant.exe powershell - c "Import-Certificate -Filepath C:\vagrant\M ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The machine wit... configured for:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

this Vagrant environment.
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that a typo in your command? Shouldn't that be `-c`instead of `- c` (mind the space) after the powershell verb.

Comment: Yeah it was. But now when I delete it I see this

`vagrant.exe : The following WinRM command responded with a non-zero exit status.
At line:1 char:2
+  vagrant.exe powershell -c "Import-Certificate -Filepath C:\vagrant\M ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

And more text which I can't put in this comment.

Comment: Also, maybe I could you -CertStoreLocation because I need this certificate in "TrustedPublisher" branch. But how should script look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Windows 2019 Core and having difficulty sharing a folder on my network; however, I am able to see, from the network, that I can reach a location shared through IIS on the VM's host machine. (running IIS with Access to a folder on the host machine)  The network uses a domain issued certificate so the certificate should be accepted but it is not.

Workaround:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback= {$true}
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServiceProtocolType]:: Tls -bor [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServiceProtocolType]:: Tls11 -bor [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServiceProtocolType]:: Tls12
$url=https://192.168.1.1/ChromeSetup.exe"
$WebClient=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebCleint.DownloadFile($url,"C:\ChromeSetup.exe")
```